# How to make Visual Studio 2008 "find all references" to work correctly?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide

Just a thing that annoys me.

When I right click on a method name a context menu appears with a "**Find All References**" option.

It works ok, *except* when you're implementing a **Interface**. Then it lists **all** references (maybe that's why it's called *Find All References*?), independent of the class that implements it.

Example:

```
interface IGetAThing<T>
{
    T Get();
}

public class ThingManager: IGetAThing<Thing>
{
    public Thing Get() {
        return new Thing();
    } 
}

public class ThingManagerReloaded: IGetAThing<Thingmabob>
{
    public Thingmabob Get() {
        return new Thingmabob();
    } 
}
```

When I search for all references of method *ThingManager->Get* I get a list containing all the references of *ThingManagerReloaded->Get* too.

What I would like is restricting the list of references to only one class references. 
Right clicking on the *ThingManagerReloaded->Get* method just shows a lists of *ThingManagerReloaded->Get* related uses, **not** including *ThingManager->Get*

Is that possible on VS2008?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ReSharper detects this and ask you if you want to find usages of the method from the base interface. If you decline it does what you ask for in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Third party tools such as resharper and coderush provide much better support for this kind of action.  If your solution is small enough and machine beefy enough, you'll probably make plenty of use for these tools.  To directly answer your question, I don't believe this is possible with VS2008 out of the box.

(You'll probably get a better answer from someone that has used these tools.)